# Start android app without launching main gui?

Tags: android

I just want an app that runs some code to shortcut to a certain part of ics. How can I run this code at run time without having to launch the main.xml? I see the manifest launches the main.xml but that is about all I know.

Comment: I created a class with a Main method so how would I make it so this is my starting point when my app launches?  I am familiar with c# but android/java is new

Comment: could You be more precise? Do You need just to run some code without UI at all or just before main ui appears?

Comment: I just need to run some code without UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of [**Service**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) Components in Android ? Service allows you to do work in background without disturbing your current GUI. You can do most of all the work that you want to hide from the user in GUI.

Have a look at example of Audio playing code, ( Original Source from [Makarana's Blog](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html). )

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.braincandy);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        player.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: probably http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html would be enough to achieve what the question author wants.

Comment: @sandrstar , agree, but example ( a simple code ) is king [How to write good answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7693/173001)

Comment: I do not want to have a gui. I need to know where/how the application starts and where I can put the code I want to run

Comment: Take the above approach, start a service in your onCreate() and then go to home screen using an Intent. That way you dont have a GUI.

Comment: Honestly I dont understand why all of that code is necessary to do something that is so simple to do in the dotnet world. What you show answers my question for the most part but I do not understand why all of this is necessary to launch a few lines of code after loading an application. I dotnet I would just create a console app and just put some code in my main method. Is this simplicity not possible in android?

Comment: Its demo code of service, rest you need to code your self as per your requirement.

Comment: I understand that but do I need to start a service just to execute code without a form?

Comment: and where you are going to code it ? **Service** is the place that allows to run code without GUI :)

Comment: Ok I guess that makes sense. I am just trying to wrap my head around this. It is all new but I thought I could just dive right in since I have c# experience but there are more differences than I thought. Thank you for your help

Comment: No Problem, we (including other users like me) are here to clear your doubts for code in right direction.

Comment: Just as reference, you only need to understand the difference between Android Activity & Service. Once you understand their usage your doubts will get clear.